# Geo Pandas Data Frame / Matrix - filter/drop NaN / False values

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix, pandas, geopandas

I applied GeoSeries.almost_equals(other[, decimal=6]) function to geo data frame with 10 mil entries, in order to find multiple geo points close to each other. 
:
[image: my data]

[image]

which gave me matrix, now i need to filter all True values in order to create DF/list with only POI that are geo related, so I used:
[image]

Now, I struggle to figure out how to proceed further with filters of this matrix.
Expected output is either vector, list or ideally DF with all TRUE (matched) values but matched to each other re 1 to 1, and repeated (if [1,9] then [9,1] to be removed from output
list example:
[image]

DF example:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post your code.

Comment: yes, i used: `data = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: (df['geometry'].T.geom_almost_equals(x,decimal=6)))` which gave  me the matrix with boolean values

Comment: Can you specify what your question actually is? Starting from the matrix of true/false, what is the result you want to obtain? Can you give an example of how this should look like?

Comment: Starting from the matrix of true/false, I would like to output which combinations are true, so ex. if row:200 and both Col 420 and 500 returns True, output will be data frame or list: 200,420,500. and so on

Comment: Can you give an example of how it should look like in a DataFrame? (the example you give now are lists)

Comment: edited with DF expample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example dataframe:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[True, False, False, True],
   ...: [False, True, True, False],
   ...: [False, True, True, False],
   ...: [True, False, False, True]])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
       0      1      2      3
0   True  False  False   True
1  False   True   True  False
2  False   True   True  False
3   True  False  False   True
```

A possible solution to get to the dataframe of matching indexes:

First I use `np.triu` to only consider the upper triangle (so you don't have duplicates):

```
In [15]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.triu(df))

In [16]: df2
Out[16]:
       0      1      2      3
0   True  False  False   True
1  False   True   True  False
2  False  False   True  False
3  False  False  False   True
```

Then I stack the dataframe, give the index levels the desired names, and select only the rows where we have 'True' values:

```
In [17]: result = df2.stack()

In [18]: result
Out[18]:
0  0     True
   1    False
   2    False
   3     True
1  0    False
   1     True
   2     True
   3    False
2  0    False
   1    False
   2     True
   3    False
3  0    False
   1    False
   2    False
   3     True
dtype: bool

In [21]: result.index.names = ['POI_id', 'matched_POI_ids']

In [23]: result[result].reset_index()
Out[23]:
   POI_id  matched_POI_ids     0
0       0                0  True
1       0                3  True
2       1                1  True
3       1                2  True
4       2                2  True
5       3                3  True
```

You can then of course delete the column with trues: `.drop(0, axis=1)`